# Multicasting in ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, tibco-rv

Is it possible to implement Tibco RV like multicasting in ActiveMQ?
i.e.
If Producer publish at X.Y.Z and there are subscriber registered with X.Y.> they will receive the message.

As per my knowledge ActiveMQ having no provision of X.Y.> like subscription, it is always point to point messaging using Topic / Queue.

Answer (score 2):

Topics are pub/sub so ActiveMQ can publish one message to multiple subscribers. It also supports wildcard topic subscriptions, so I think the answer is yes all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

I think in terms of functionality you are looking for wildcard subscriptions, not multicasting.

It's possible to do wildcard subscriptions on ActiveMQ topics (take a look e.g. here http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html ;))

Multicast messaging in a strict sense means sending exactly one message over a network for n subscribers which is a decentral way of messaging like TIBCO Rv implements. Active MQ is a central hub/spoke message broker that will create a copy of the original message for each client in the subscription.

Both can implement wildcard subscriptions but each implementation (central/decentral) has a different impact on performance, easy of central control etc..(e.g. TIBCO Rv will have a magnitude higher throughput depending on network capacity then a central JMS broker like ActiveMQ)